# Get current item when it is selected in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering

I have a document library in sharepoint online and I want to get currently selected item's attribute values whenever I change the selection.

I am looking for a CSR

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use CSR or just plain JSOM depends on what you intend to do with the selected items. If you want to get the Selectd List item attributes, you can just use the SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems() method as part of JSOM code. Below code gets the Title value of all selected list items.

```
function getSelectedItems(success,error)
{
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //selected list Id
var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //selected Items Ids

var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
var listItems = [];
for (idx in selectedItemIds)
{
    var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
    listItems.push(item);
    context.load(item);
}
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
      success(listItems);       
   },
   error); 
}

//Usage
getSelectedItems(function(items){
for (var i =0 ; i < items.length;i++)
{
   console.log(items[i].get_item('Title'));  
}  
},function(sender,args){
console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
});
```

[Get Selected Items Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832967/get-selected-items-in-a-list-sharepoint-online)

[Another Implementation](https://www.spums.be/how-to-enumerate-the-selected-list-items-with-javascript/)